# Get color of Pixel from an image

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, dart, pixel

I try to get the color of an Pixel in an Image .

Via the Image class of the `package:image/image.dart` package, i can access the pixel at a given coordinate x and y.

This gives me a integer.

How can i get the color from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the integer into its color parts using

```
    int c1 = image.getPixel(x, y);
    int r1 = getRed(c1);
    int g1 = getGreen(c1);
    int b1 = getBlue(c1);
    int a1 = getAlpha(c1);
```

See also https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/master/test/color_test.dart for an example